# Where to put custom page templates in theme?

Tags: theme-development, page-template, template-hierarchy

I am building a theme (parent theme) and I was advised to put custom page templates in theme root folder. I am copying theme twenty fourteen and found this theme using a separate directory called **`page-templates`** for keeping custom page templates but it does not work with my theme?

Can i know why twenty fourteen doing this and how ? Do I need to do the same because this is WordPress theme and I think they do everything thing in a proper way.

Comment: [The WordPress Handbook](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/page-templates/#file-organization-of-page-templates) says: `WordPress recognizes the subfolder page-templates. Therefore, it’s a good idea to store your global page templates in this folder to help keep them organized.` - - - This may mean that it's an issues with *how* you're setting up your templates, are you adding the comments [as seen here](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/page-templates/#creating-custom-page-templates-for-global-use)?

Comment: how dumb i am :(  checking then whats wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Where to put custom page templates in theme?

Custom page templates in `page-templates` folder are automatically recognized by WordPress.This folder is recommended for global or multi-purpose page-templates.

You can check more [organizing theme files](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/organizing-theme-files/#page-templates-folder) on theme development handbook.

> but it does not work with my theme?

Are you sure you have template files with the correct header ?

Answer (score 0):

You can put custom page template in theme: create "templates" folder in theme and put the page.
First you check the admin panel and create new page display template name in "Page Attributes", like:

[image]

If is not, then open `archive.php` in given this line:

```
<?php
/**
 * The template for displaying Archive pages
 *
 * Used to display archive-type pages if nothing more specific matches a query.
 * For example, puts together date-based pages if no date.php file exists.
 *
 * If you'd like to further customize these archive views, you may create a
 * new template file for each specific one. For example, Twenty Thirteen
 * already has tag.php for Tag archives, category.php for Category archives,
 * and author.php for Author archives.
 *
 * @link http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy
 *
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Twenty_Thirteen
 * @since Twenty Thirteen 1.0
 */
```

**Replace This Line**

```
<?php 
/*
Template Name: About Us
*/
```

and Refresh your admin panel, creating the new page.

Remember for all created custom page templates, make sure to write the code:

```
<?php 
/*
Template Name: Contact Us
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

Put Template name (should be separate name) on page template php file (on toop). like this:

```
<?php /* Template Name: Page Template Name */ ?>
```

your file name can be template-your_template_name.php in theme folder or in subfolder in your theme folder.